# Active Directory Sync to Remote Domain

Tags: active-directory, synchronization

I have a client that needs to sync certain object AD info from their secure domain to our domain.

Something like the Windows Azure Directory Sync Tool, but just not for Azure.

I would like to use some Microsoft tool and not a 3rd party tool, and I would also not want to buy a tool for this.

I know FIM can sync AD data but that is not an option at the moment.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Azure DirSync is a stripped-down version of FIM, from what I've read. If FIM isn't an option, there isn't anything native from Microsoft that will sync directories. Because they've already got it, and it's called FIM.

You could do scheduled LDAP or CSV exports and imports and then schedule file transfers, that could be done using native tools. That won't sync any encrypted info like passwords, which is for the best.

Hint - describe the business problem that you're really trying to solve, so we can see the whole picture, and perhaps advise you of a better approach. For example, ADFS is often a better solutions than syncing AD domains.

Comment: A user object is created in the AD of the Client because they have existing portals referencing these objects for login details, we need a one-way sync to our Hosted Exchange environment where we then add the Exchange and Lync attributes. Passwords will always only be changed on the client's AD. (They actually have TDS syncing to a secure domain with FIM which in turn need to sync to us).

Comment: Then, if you only need those attributes, a set of scheduled tasks for export->transfer->Mangle if needed->import should work just fine.

Comment: I can set up scripts to do the exports and compare / imports. Do I need PES to export the passwords?

Comment: You stated in your comment that you only needed exchange and lync attributes. Using PES from ADMT for this seems like a bad idea; it's not what it was meant for.

Comment: I might have not come across correct, we need Name, Last Name, SamAccountName and Password to sync from the client. Sorry English is not my first language :)

Comment: So, if you're doing authentication, you should try ADFS. That's what it's for.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/17360/discussion-between-shawn-gradwell-and-mfinni).